# the right way to synchronise sources on freebsd

Tags: freebsd, amazon-ec2, jails

**Update**: I'm happy to report @dartonw 's answer worked and I went and did a checkout and then buildworld and it built successfully in about 6 hours.

---

So I've been having some issues with jails in freebsd. I run **FreeBSD9.1 64 bit on EC2** as a small instance. I recently tried :

```
cd /usr/src;make buildworld
```

And after nine hours of compiling it gives me :

```
{standard input}:12044: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:12142: Error: invalid character '_' in mnemonic
c++: Internal error: Killed: 9 (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
*** [TransAutoreleasePool.o] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src/lib/clang/libclangarcmigrate.
*** [all] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src/lib/clang.
*** [all] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src/lib.
*** [lib__L] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src.
*** [libraries] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src.
*** [_libraries] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src.
*** [buildworld] Error code 1
Stop in /usr/src.
```

I came across [this article](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28650) which says :

```
Let's synchronise sources.


    # cd /usr/share/examples/cvsup/
    # cp standard-supfile /etc/freebsd-supfile

The list CVSup mirror sites is here.
```

But, the [link](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/cvsup.html#CVSUP-MIRRORS) says:

> Warning: cvsup has been deprecated by the project, and its use is not recommended. Subversion should be used instead.

What should I do then? Where can I find an updated article? Should I update my ports collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Subversion in basically the same way as documented for cvsup. In short:

```
# portsnap update
# cd /usr/ports/devel/subversion
# make install clean
```

Then to update /usr/src (assuming you have sources installed):

```
# svn update /usr/src
```

If sources are not already installed in /usr/src, you can check out a fresh working copy:

```
# svn checkout svn+ssh://svn.freebsd.org/base/head /usr/src
```

See [Using Subversion](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/svn.html) in the FreeBSD Handbook for more options. You can get more information on using Subversion in general at the [Subversion Primer](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/committers-guide/subversion-primer.html).

Unless you want to customize the ports (i.e. make local changes to the source code), use `portsnap`. It is the official replacement for the port management functionality previously handled by cvsup and will probably meet most of your needs. See [portsnap](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-portsnap.html) in the FreeBSD Handbook for a detailed but easy to follow guide.

Comment: won't portsnap fill the `/usr/ports` for various software? I'm having trouble building `/usr/src`

Comment: You are correct, answer updated. I'm not quite clear on why you would take the somewhat drastic step of rebuilding world though?

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. Is there any other way? My jails don't seem to work write, I can't run the `ezjail-admin update -ip`, which complains that I should `build world`.

Comment: Ok, also (I'm somewhat familiar with svn) so `/base/head/` in the svn url will point to the latest?

Comment: "head" will be the latest, you can use `svn+ssh://svn.freebsd.org/base/releng/9.1` for a specific version. It's worth noting that if you are used to `csvup`, the `svn` package has a *lot* more dependencies, though it has one advantage at least, you can easily checkout over `http://` too.